# Do the terms of $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \ln \bigg|\frac{\alpha - n}{\alpha + n}\bigg|$ go towards zero, and does the sum converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $0 < \alpha <1$ and consider the summation

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \ln \bigg|\frac{\alpha - n}{\alpha + n}\bigg|.$$

Am I correct in thinking that the individual terms in this series go towards zero as $n$ gets large because the argument supplied to $\ln$ goes towards $1$? What does the summation converge to?

Comment: For fixed $\alpha$, the summands are $\sim \frac1{n 2}$, hence the series does converge.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You mean that the terms are more like $1/n$ and the series diverge, right? (also, to OP, you mean $0<\alpha<1$, right?)

Comment: $$\lim_{\infty}\ln \bigg|\frac{\alpha - n}{\alpha + n}\bigg|=0$$
is a necessary condition for convergentness not sufficient.

Comment: @MyGlasses Ah, sign error! I thought the odd powers would cancel, but the even ones do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0<\alpha<1$ and $n\geq 1$ you can write
$$
\ln\Bigl|\frac{\alpha-n}{\alpha+n}\Bigr|=\ln\frac{n-\alpha}{n+\alpha}=\ln\Bigl(1-\frac{2\alpha}{n+\alpha}\Bigr).
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}
\frac{\ln\Bigl(1-\frac{2\alpha}{n+\alpha}\Bigr)}{-\frac{2\alpha}{n+\alpha}}=1
$$
and all terms in your series are negative we conclude that your series converges if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2\alpha}{n+\alpha}
$$
converges, which we(?) know that it does not.

Comment: Thanks I see how to approach it now!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \ln \bigg|\frac{\alpha - n}{\alpha + n}\bigg|.
$

For any real $a$,
once $n > |a|$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln \bigg|\frac{a-n}{a+n}\bigg|
&=\ln \frac{n-a}{n+a}\\
&=\ln \frac{1-a/n}{1+a/n}\\
&=\ln (1-a/n)-\ln(1+a/n)\\
&=-\frac{a}{n}-\frac{a^2}{2n^2}+O(\frac{a^3}{n^3})-(\frac{a}{n}-\frac{a^2}{2n^2}+O(\frac{a^3}{n^3}))\\
&=-\frac{2a}{n}+O(\frac{a^3}{n^3})\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these diverges.